# Compiling ffmpeg for chromium on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg, cygwin, chromium

I am following the instructions [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/third_party/ffmpeg/+/master/chromium/scripts/build_ffmpeg.py#83) to generate the gn files for Chromium. I have installed the cygwin base package along with diffutils, nasm, make and python.

Also, I have copied chromium/scripts/cygwin-wrapper to /usr/local/bin

1. Started C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat
2. Started C:\cygwin\cygwin.bat
3. cd to third_party\chromium\scripts
4. python build_ffmpeg win ia32

I am getting some warnings plus this:

Could not create temporary library.
make: *** [/cygdrive/d/src/chromium/src/third_party/ffmpeg/ffbuild/library.mak:102: libavutil/avutil-56.dll] Error 1

make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

**Could not create temporary library.**

Could not create temporary library.

make: *** [/cygdrive/d/src/chromium/src/third_party/ffmpeg/ffbuild/library.mak:102: libavcodec/avcodec-58.dll] Error 1

make: *** [/cygdrive/d/src/chromium/src/third_party/ffmpeg/ffbuild/library.mak:102: libavformat/avformat-58.dll] Error 1

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "build_ffmpeg.py", line 900, in

sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))

File "build_ffmpeg.py", line 502, in main

options=options)

File "build_ffmpeg.py", line 876, in ConfigureAndBuild

configure_args)

File "build_ffmpeg.py", line 870, in do_build_ffmpeg

options.config_only, branding, configure_flags)

File "build_ffmpeg.py", line 408, in BuildFFmpeg

['make', '-j%d' % parallel_jobs] + libraries, cwd=config_dir)

File "build_ffmpeg.py", line 106, in PrintAndCheckCall

subprocess.check_call(argv, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call

raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', '-j8', 'libavcodec/avcodec-
58.dll', 'libavformat/avformat-58.dll', 'libavutil/avutil-56.dll']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Comment: It seems a permission problem in the directory

Comment: You don't need Cygwin, it works fine with VS 2017 installed and the bundled clang compiler

Comment: @Asesh Do you have any reference to perform this directly on VS 2017 without cygwin ? I was just following the guidelines by chromium developers.

Comment: @ykhandel You don't have to manually build FFMPEG. Just pass this build flag when building Chromium: ``ffmpeg_branding = "Chrome"`` or specify that build argument in your ``args.gn`` which should be located in your build folder.

Comment: This post should be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50987960/4781312